# No route matches [GET] "/edit_user/1" ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have write down this in routes file

```
resources :users
match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: [:POST, :get, :post]
match '/edit_user', to: 'users#edit', via: 'get'
```

and this is my function in users controller

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

I am getting error Please help me..

No route matches [GET] "/edit_user/1"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match '/edit_user', to: 'users#edit', via: 'get'
```

You are missing the /:id on the route. Fixed:

```
match '/edit_user/:id', to: 'users#edit', via: 'get'
```